# Can't get PHP Regex working

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use PHP regular expressions. I've tried this code:

```
$regex = "c:(.+),";
$input = "otherStuff094322f98c:THIS,OtherStuffHeree129j12dls";
$match = Array();
preg_match_all($regex, $input, $match);
```

It should return a sub-string `THIS` ("c" and ":" followed by any character combination followed by ",") from `$input`. But it returns a empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong? Not turning on `error_reporting` for one. That would have hinted at the delimiter situation.

Comment: I can't configure the interpreter as I want, otherwise I would have already did that.

Comment: You can configure error_reporting() at runtime.  `error_reporting(E_ALL);`  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: That's a good one, thank you! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need the slashes to make regex working.

and using `.+` will match everything behind the comma too, which is you don't want. Use `.+?` or `[^,]+`

```
$regex = "/c:(.+?),/";
```

or

```
$regex = "/c:([^,]+),/";
```

Comment: And the group should be non-greedy `(.+?)` or better, use `([^,]+)` to get everything up to the next comma.

Comment: Why do I need slashes? And what does "non-greedy" mean?

Comment: `.+?` will match as few as characters as possible before satisfying the next token (in this case, the comma `,`)

Comment: In fact, the use of slashes are more apparent if you use some regex flags. For example, `/abc/i` will match `abc` case-insensitively, that is `/abc/i` will also match `Abc`, `ABC`, `aBc` etc... For reasons of slashes, see below.

Comment: More specifically than slashes, PCREs require [delimeters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).  Any symbol excepting backslash will do, though `/` is the default convention.

Comment: You need slashes because regexes have a begin and end delimiter. The `/` is the most common delimiter, also across languages. PHP does allow you to use other characters, ie `~`.